# How do I call a function within a function? (CoffeeScript)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a function I created getData() which is within another function, and when I try to call it I get in the console "getData is not defined". I tried @getData() and that does not work either. Is this even possible to do within the function?

```
class SomeCollection

   parse: (data) =>

       handleData: (data) ->
          return data

       getData: ->
          Session.ajax
          url: "someurl"
          type: 'get'

       getData().done handleData
```

I've also tried putting those functions outside of the parse() function but whenever i try to reference getData() or @getData() it always gives me the error that it's not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the colon since that's for defining property values. Use an equals sign:

```
getData = () =>
 alert('hello!');

getData()
```

**JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/etuy0t2c/**

Answer (score 2):

It's not *entirely* clear what you're trying to do, but change those `:`s to `=`s and indent the two lines after `Session.ajax`, and at least it will make some amount of sense:

```
class SomeCollection

   parse: (data) =>

       handleData = (data) ->
          return data

       getData = ->
          Session.ajax
             url: "someurl"
             type: 'get'

       getData().done handleData
```

Your `parse` method's `data` parameter is not used anywhere, but hopefully you realize that.

Comment: I think the issue was the :'s as it's working for me now. Thank you! Yes, I left out the parse method's data handling in this example.